# Converting a polynomial system to one of degree 2 efficiently

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

it is a well known fact that given a polynomial system $\mathcal{F}(x)=b,\;\;\mathcal{F}:\mathbb{K}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{K}^m$ of arbitrary degree (meaning the max degree of any monomial of $\mathcal{F}$) it is possible to find another system $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}(x)=b$ equivalent, but $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ having degree $2$.

However the domain and codomain of $\mathcal{F}$ may me much larger than that of $\mathcal{F}$.

For example, consider the following system:
$$
x^5+x^3=1
$$
We can work our way up from the lowest monomial, by considering $x^3=yx;\; y=x^2$ and so on, to obtain:
$$
zy+xy=1
\\y=x^2\\
z=xy
$$

We might also proceed by first considering $x^5=x_4 x;\; x_4=x^4$ and so on, to obtain:
$$
x_4+x_2x=1\\
x_4=x_3x\\
x_3=x^2
$$

This also gives us an upper bound on the dimension of the domain of $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$, being: $n\cdot(\text{deg}(\mathcal{F})-1)$.

In both of these cases, we obtain the same system, is this always the case? Or is there a known way of obtaining an equivalent system with the minimal amount possible of equations?